# How to Get POST ID from one page to another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a message system in wordpress. There s a consultation page fr each user.also a sidebar with certain menus. when the submit button is clicked the admin reviews the question and answers it. The message will be shown in the inbox sidebar menu on the same consultation page.

but whtever i tried am not getting the reply message of the corresponding user. my problem is that when i defined the link for inbox there is no id being passed.later in tht particular page whtever id s am calling its bring up the page id only and nothing else.

This is the sidebar code:

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/inbox/?id=<?php echo get_current_user_id();?>"><i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc " aria-hidden="true"> </i> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Inbox</span>  </a>
</li>
```

now its bringing the id = 1. no matter which user it is.

this is the inbox code:

```
<?php
global $post;
$idd= $post->ID;

$title= $post->post_title;
var_dump($title);

echo "<div class= 'col-lg-4'><table style='width:500px;'><tr><td><b>Reply:</b>&nbsp;".get_post_meta( $idd, 'docreply', true)."</td></tr></div>";

echo "<div class= 'col-lg-4'><table style='width:500px;'><tr><td><b>Amount:</b>&nbsp;".get_post_meta( $idd, 'amount', true)."</td></tr></div>";
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b2pL.p]

Answer (score 1):

you can get the post id by using get_the_ID() function.

```
<?php
echo get_the_ID();
?>
```

Comment: Thank yu for the help but IT ONLY BRINGS THE CURRENT PAGE ID. I want to pass post id of the corresponding user when he clicks on "Inbox".

Comment: you are passing user id. you can get the different user id not post id.
<?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]; ?>

Comment: no matter whtever am trying am not getting the post id which contains the post meta data of admin reply !! \

Comment: you can create <li>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/inbox/?id=<?php echo get_current_user_id();?>&page_id=5"><i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-asc " aria-hidden="true"> </i> <span style="margin-left:10px;">Inbox</span>  </a>
</li>
<?php
echo $_REQUEST["id"];
echo $_REQUEST["page_id"];
?>

Comment: it is not getting because your page is inbox. so every time it will get inbox post id.

Comment: Yes am getting the page id =15 over there . My user id is 1 and its corresponding post_id is 13. am trying to get this post_id and its post_meta data over there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146071/discussion-between-jackson-and-shital-marakana).

Answer (score 1):

Where is the message data saved?

I see you calling the page URL with the ID of the currently logged user.

Later, you're using the ID of the page then fetching two meta values and displaying them.

If you're using post meta, use the ID of the user that is logged in and get the meta value by using get_user_meta - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

More code would help solve this easier :)

Comment: If there's no relation to the current user, all users will see the same information when fetching the meta.

You should associate the messages to the users, and then display them on the page.

I'm not sure if the post_meta will help you in this case.

I just noticed your comment on the answer below:
"My user id is 1 and its corresponding post_id is 13"

Are you saving this relation somewhere in the database?

Comment: No am not saving the relation, and am trying to achieve that. Bt am getting nowhere

Comment: You can add a meta to the user, which contains his inbox page ID, when the admin answers the question. Or assign it some other way.

Then, I think you know how things are going to happen.

By accessing the inbox page with the ID of the user as a parameter, you'll get their corresponding inbox ID (by using the meta you saved it to earlier), and use that when fetching the meta.

It might be a better idea, to save each question as a separate post from a post type - "Questions". That way, when a user sends a question, you'll add their ID to the post and use it later on their inbox page.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have found a solution to my problem. I updated the post_meta values in to my user_meta and in the page where i need to display the data, i called the current user id and called the user_meta